# NFT Contract not showing the token value

Tags: solidity, nft

I am trying to create a NFT token by using the openzeppelin and chainlink. Everything works fine from compile to migrate.
But when i try to check my contract https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x43ab0d52074df93b1539ab4467bc435c3a6e6fa0, Its not showing the Token like **0.1 LINK** similar to the below screenshot.

[image]

Contract File:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721URIStorage, VRFConsumerBase {

    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;
    uint256 public tokenCounter;

    enum Breed{PUG, SHIBA_INU, ST_BERNARD}

    mapping(bytes32 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToTokenURI;
    mapping(uint256 => Breed) public tokenIdToBreed;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public requestIdToTokenId;

    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId);

    constructor(address _VRFCoordinator, address _LinkToken, bytes32 _keyHash)
        public
        VRFConsumerBase(_VRFCoordinator, _LinkToken) 
        ERC721("Doggies", "DOG") 
        {
            keyHash = _keyHash;
            fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18;   // 0.1 LINK
            tokenCounter = 0;
        }

    function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI) public returns (bytes32) 
    {
        require(
            LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee,
            "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
        );

        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        requestIdToTokenURI[requestId] = tokenURI;

        emit requestedCollectible(requestId);

        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber) 
        internal 
        override 
    {
        address dogOwner = requestIdToSender[requestId];
        string memory tokenURI = requestIdToTokenURI[requestId];
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;

        _safeMint(dogOwner, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        Breed breed = Breed(randomNumber % 3);
        tokenIdToBreed[newItemId] = breed;
        requestIdToTokenId[requestId] = newItemId;
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    }

    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public
    {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not approved"
        );

        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

Migration:

```
const AdvancedCollectible = artifacts.require("AdvancedCollectible");

const VRFCoordinator  = '0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B';
const LinkToken       = '0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709';
const KeyHash         = '0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311';

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(AdvancedCollectible, VRFCoordinator, LinkToken, KeyHash).then((instance) => {
    console.log('Testing AC: ', instance);
  });

};
```

The above address like vrfcoordinator, link and keyhash i have copied from Chainlink [VRF Contracts](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#rinkeby) documentation.
Could someone please point me to the right direction?

**Note:** Only ETH deducted from my wallet not the LINK during the migration.

Comment: Hi jogesh_pi! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! I don't see a transfer of LINK tokens to your contract on etherscan, have you transferred tokens externally? The migration script doesn't do any token transfer.

Comment: @Ismael, Thank you for you response. As you can see at ```constructor``` there is a fee assigned i assume it is the LINK token? TBH i am not sure. I am following a tutorial provided by https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/57451/patrick-collins, i also updated the screenshot that he got after the migration and all the code are same.

Comment: I don't know what tutorial are you following but the code is just assigning a value, it doesn't do any transfer of tokens. Check for extra steps in the tutorial.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for your help. Sorry, my bad, You are correct. i missed the part to fund the collectible.

Comment: Great! It would be nice if you could those steps as the answer to mark the question as resolved so it will help others in a similar situation.